# Manage multiple types of Firebase Push Notifications in android app

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to have 3 different types of notifications with different sounds in my app (Received from FCM)
Each of these types of notification has a specific sound and user is able to mute each type of notification.
But I can't change notification channel config after it has been created to set its specific sound.
How can I handle this situation ?